# Is there a way to make ListNode and node.val function properly in this code?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have the following code and 'ListNode' as well as 'val' in node.val are in color red, denoting that it is not registering them. Also 'Node' type is not being registered. I thought Node was something like 'int', 'double' and such.

```
class Solution {
    public void deleteNode(ListNode node) {
        while(node.next != null) {
            int temp = node.val;
            node.val = node.next.val;
            node.next.val = temp;
            if(node.next.next == null) {
                node.next = null;
                break;
            }
            node = node.next;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListNode val = [4,5,1,9],;
        Solution obj = new Solution();

        val = obj.deleteNode(val);
        for (Node node = val; node != null; node = node.next) {
            System.out.println(node.data);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is ListNode defined?

Comment: ‘ListNode val = ‘ or is there a package that needs to be imported?

Comment: I don't know, this is *your* code. You need to learn to create a [mre] so that somebody could have put this into a debugger and answered the question.

Comment: I’ve worked with other linklist problems and ‘Node’ is utilized as a type. In the same way as ‘int’ and ‘double’ are used. I thought the same applied to ListNode since it has it as an argument in the method.

Comment: You will have to define it or import it.

Comment: I don’t know which library has it. Is there a way to just use ‘Node’?

Comment: No. You have to program this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next = null;

    public ListNode(int d) {
        val = d;
        ListNode next = null;
    }

    ListNode appendToTail(int d) {
        ListNode end = new ListNode(d);
        ListNode n = this;
        while (n.next != null) {
            n = n.next;
        }
        n.next = end;
        return end;
    }



    public void deleteNode(ListNode node) {
        while(node.next != null) {
            int temp = node.val;
            node.val = node.next.val;
            node.next.val = temp;
            if(node.next.next == null) {
                node.next = null;
                break;
            }
            node = node.next;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListNode val = new ListNode(4);

        val.appendToTail(5);
        val.appendToTail(1);
        val.appendToTail(9);
       
        val.deleteNode(val.next.next);

        for (ListNode node = val; node != null; node = node.next) {
            System.out.println(node.val);
        }

    }
}
```